# Opening multiple Non-Office files through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, file, loops, hyperlink

This macro is suppose to open multiple Hyperlinked CAD files in a list on an excel document. I have to use this list (using excel cells, not a drop-down) for our infrastructure.

After the first instance is met and the first file opens, the code stops. I think this is because when a non-office application is opened, the macro stops because excel is not the active application at that point.

```
Sub OpenCadFiles()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim excel As Workbook
  Set excel = ActiveWorkbook

  Dim j As Long
  For j = 32 To 133 Step 1

      If ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 14).Value <> "" And Rows([j]).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
          URL = Cells(j, 14).Text
          'ShellExecute "explorer.exe " & URL, vbNormalFocus
          ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink URL
          excel.Activate
      Else
      End If
  Next j

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Are my assumptions correct, is this not possible to do in excel VBA? If not, does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach almost works. You should use ActiveSheet (or Active anything) sparingly since the user could change applications while the macro runs. This is especially true if the macro takes a long time and the user checks his or her e-mail in the in meantime, for example. A better approach would be:

```
Sub OpenCadFiles()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
  Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

  Dim currentWorksheet As Worksheet
  Set currentWorksheet = ActiveSheet

  Dim URL As String
  Dim j As Long
  For j = 32 To 133
      If currentWorksheet.Cells(j, 14).Value <> "" And Rows([j]).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
          URL = currentWorksheet.Cells(j, 14).Text
          currentWorkbook.FollowHyperlink URL
      End If
  Next j

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

By using currentWorkbook and currentWorksheet only once, you're guaranteed the correct references are always made.

Comment: Awesome! That did it. I also learned something new. Thank You!

Comment: Excellent. Don't forget to up vote and accept the answers you like.